# Server Services Installed But Missing From Services List

Tags: service

I have a Windows Server 2016 running as a WSUS Server. Since a few updates ago the services for WSUS are missing from the Service List.

If you do a `Get-WindowsFeatures` it shows that it is installed. If you use command line to `net stop/start` you can manage the services. However the services are missing from the Services MMC Console. Services Include:

Update Service
IIS Admin
WSUS Server
WSUS CertServer

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the feature and they will not come back. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Could be that the service permissions have been corrupted somehow.  Can you post the output of `sc sdshow` for one of the affected services?  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736814/886887) on Stack Overflow.